# Code: 4010 - Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, connection

I have seen a similar error on stackoverflow, but with a different code (so maybe it is not the same?). Any how I have been thrown this error spontaneously. Sometimes after 20 seconds of starting my instance (and launching SSH in browser), sometimes after 30 minutes, but it completely shuts down my instance.

```
Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed
Code: 4010
Reason: destination read failed
You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.
```

If I click the "Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy" button I am getting:

```
Connection Failed
We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue.
```

Any idea what is happening? I havn't done any changes in my instance settings for a long time.

Answer (score 15):

The issue regarding the Identity-Aware Proxy(**IAP**) connection to the instance is due to the lack of a [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule) `allow-ingress-from-iap` with this IP ranges `35.235.240.0/20` that needs to be configured when using IAP.

To Allow SSH access to all VM instances in your network, do the following:

1- Open the Firewall Rules page `(Navigation menu > VPC network > Firewall)` and click **Create firewall rule**

2- Configure the following settings:

- **Name:** `allow-ingress-from-iap`
- **Direction of traffic: Ingress**
- **Target: All instances in the network**
- **Source filter: IP ranges**
- **Source IP ranges:** `35.235.240.0/20`
- **Protocols and ports:** Select **TCP** and enter `22` to allow **SSH**

3- Click **Create**

Comment: Wow! Thanks man. I havn't seen to have had errors since. :-) You are the best

Comment: @LorenzWeb I’m glad to know that my answer helped you, please try to accept the answer or vote it (mark as useful), this will help others if they have the same issue and will improve the experience for everyone in this community