# Google VM instance Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed (code 4010)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, cloud, virtual-machine, firewall

Even though I created a firewall rule to allow ssh as recommended in this post ([Code: 4010 - Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137100/code-4010-connection-via-cloud-identity-aware-proxy-failed)), I still have this a connection error 4010 (Reason: destination read failed).[image]

When I stop and resume the machine, I can open the terminal in the browser and run some commands. But when I try to npm run build my react app, it takes forever to build (it is building very fast in my laptop). And after a while, the connection fails and I have to stop and resume the VM to reconnect to it. I am using a e2-micro (2 vCPUs, 1 GB memory) machine running ubuntu
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Your problem is not SSH. I think your problem is a too small VM. Edit your question with details on what you have deployed.

Comment: Is it possible to change the machine once you've deployed it?

Comment: Yes, you can resize larger in the Goog Cloud Console GUI or via the CLI.

Comment: Also make sure you are not running out of disk space.

Comment: thank you @JohnHanley. I resized it to e2 medium and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per above question and screenshot it seems you don’t have any issues with your SSH connection. You are using an **e2-micro** (2 vCPUs, 1 GB memory) machine running ubuntu VM. you can try  to migrate / resize your VM from e2-micro to higher capacity VM.

By using this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance) you can migrate your VM and also you can resize a persistent [disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/working-with-persistent-disks#resize_pd) online without stopping or rebooting the VM, without taking snapshots, and without having to restore it to a larger disk.

**Changing the machine type/size:**

1. In the google cloud **console**, go to the VM instances
2. Select the **VM** (which VM you want to migrate)
3. **Stop** the VM and click **edit** button
4. Change the **machine configuration** and other details
5. Click **save** and **start** the VM.

**Changing the disk size:**

1. In the Google Cloud **Console**, go to the **Disks** page.
2. In the list of **persistent disks** in your project, click the name of the **disk** that you want to resize.
3. On the **disk** details page, click **Edit**.
4. In the **Size field**, enter the new size for your disk. Disks with MBR partition tables can resize only up to 2 TB.
5. Click **Save** to apply your changes to the **disk**.