# Unable to connect to Google Cloud VM via SSH Error code 4010

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, connection, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

Unable to connect to Google Cloud VM via SSH.

I have faced the below-mentioned error while trying to connect VM.
[image]

So far I have tried following things,

[Code: 4010 - Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137100/code-4010-connection-via-cloud-identity-aware-proxy-failed)

[Google VM instance Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed (code 4010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69770172/google-vm-instance-connection-via-cloud-identity-aware-proxy-failed-code-4010)

Could you please tell me anyone is this issue is related to any SSH key. I thought ssh key has been expired. So, I have generate new SSH private & public key via PUTTY Gen
Then I have update public key in **Google cloud->Metadata->SSH Keys -> Edit**
Followed many documents to generate ssh key & add ssh key

I am unable to add ssh key in **Instance-> Edit-> SSH key** facing below mentioned error.

[image]

Need to start tomcat service imediately last 12 hours service has been stopped due to this issue. Could you please suggest any way to start atleast apache tomcat service?. Please let me know if need any clarification.
Could you please help me anyone to resolve this issue.

Don't mark as duplicate question. It's related to someother issue. I have already checked existing forums. Not working.

Comment: Oh my... please don't take pictures of your monitor with a camera. If you don't know how to take screenshots, please spend time learning it.

Answer (score 2):

1. How should we know the SSH key is expired?

```
<protocol> <key-blob> google-ssh {"userName":"<username@example.com>","expireOn":"<date>"}
```

You can check out `expireOn`.

2. The common solution is the firewall. Please check your firewall is configured correctly and open on the port you're connecting to. You can use [Connectivity Tests](https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/how-to/running-connectivity-tests) to identify any connectivity issues.
3. Also, you should be able to see the instance's [serial console output](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/viewing-serial-port-output) using the GCP console - go to the instance's details and click on Serial port 1 (console) and you will see the output.
4. GCP has provided the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) of troubleshooting.

The second issue shows that you're facing some IP problems, so I still suggest that review any network service that you using.