# Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed Code: 4010 Reason: destination read failed on Google Cloud Console

Tags: console, cloud, virtual-machine

I can't seem to access the terminal at all, since as soon as I click on SSH it gives me this error "Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed
Code: 4010 Reason: destination read failed"

I have tried following this  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63141139/12830311)

but it hasn't made a difference

Comment: I have the same problem, today is the first time I noticed it. I have 15 instances, some of them connect fine, some of them not. The software on the instances appeared to be running correctly. I created a new instance from a snapshot, at first it also had the same error, then spontaneously allowed connections. I selected "create similar" from that image, and all of the instances created this way have the same error and I can't connect via SSH. I can connect the serial console to all of them.

Comment: I have created an issue on Google's issue tracker, so if you're still experiencing the problem can you add a "star" to it to increase visibility? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228091306

Comment: Further investigation has revealed that *resetting* the instance (not stopping/starting, but resetting) fixes this issue for me. In most cases the VMs that were having the problem wouldn't even stop, but could be reset and deleted. At present, I can't SSH into a VM created from a snapshot without resetting it first. So I have to create the VM, reset it, then I can login.

Comment: The Google team have replied to my ticket on their issue tracker and said they're aware of the problem, but don't have an ETA for a fix yet. At least resetting the instance seems like a workaround for now.